# Linux - copy files if column 5 in a file contains "V"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, exec

I have  number of csv files (like tmo_2019*). In these files some files have 5th column value as V.
I want to copy those files having 5th column value as V to specific directory /test/V_files/.

I tried to extract file names by below but not able to complete command for copy.

```
find -type f -iname "tmo*"  -exec awk -F',' '$5 == "V" {print FILENAME}'  {} \;
```

How to complete command to copy these files having 5th column value as V.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Does each file contain just a single line?

Comment: each file has more than 1 lines having some fields on 5th position other than "V"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find's `-exec` can be used as a filter: if the executed program returns zero, it's "true"

```sh
find -type f -iname "tmo*" \
  -exec awk -F, -v status=1 '$5 == "V" {status=0; exit} END {exit status}' {} \; \
  -exec cp -vt /test/V_files {} +
```